# Why do keep getting this error, I'm trying to turn a character invisible when the function runs

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local camera = workspace.CurrentCamera
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local player = Players.LocalPlayer
local startergui = game:GetService("StarterGui")
local char = Players.LocalPlayer.Character

local model = workspace.OceanVillagedr201["Wine Cellar"].WineDigitalkeypad
local screen = model.screen

local replicated_storage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local CheckCode = Instance.new("RemoteEvent")
CheckCode.Name = "CheckWineCellarCodeEvent"
CheckCode.Parent = replicated_storage

local function Entercode(player)
    Players.LocalPlayer.Character.Humanoid.RootPart.Anchored = true
    for _,p in pairs(char:GetChildren()) do
         p.Transparency = 1
    end
    game.StarterGui = replicated_storage.EnterWineCellarCode
end
screen.ProximityPrompt.Triggered:Connect(function(player)
   Entercode()
end)
```

> Im attempting to create a function that triggers when the proximity prompt is triggered, One piece of this *Entercode()* function is to toggle the playermodel's Transparency from 0 to 1 and Remove the Characters ability to move.

```
    local function Entercode(player)
    print("went")
    Players.LocalPlayer.Character.Humanoid.RootPart.Anchored = true
    for _,p in pairs(char:GetChildren()) do
         p.Transparency = 1
    end
```

> But Im having trouble with this Piece. It keeps telling me "*attempt to index nil*" with anything dealing with trying to reference the Characters model. **(FFC(), GetChildren(), Player.LocalPlayer.Character, etc.)**. I am using a local script because I plan to create a Remote Function for the result of EnterCode()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is that the character either **was not spawned** at the time of making `char` *or* **is an old character** (player respawned & a new character was made). A quick fix would be to redeclare `char` inside `Entercode`:

```lua
local function Entercode()
    char = player.Character
    char.Humanoid.RootPart.Anchored = true
    for _, p in pairs(char:GetChildren()) do
        if p:IsA("BasePart") then
            p.Transparency = 1
        end
    end
    replicated_storage.EnterWineCellarCode.Parent = player.PlayerGui
end
```

There were also a number of other errors, here are a few changes I made:

```lua
local function Entercode()
```

In the original code, **`player` was a parameter but was not sent as an argument** Good thing you set the player variable at the beginning of the code.

```lua
if p:IsA("BasePart") then
    p.Transparency = 1
end
```

In the original code, **you didn't check to see if `p` was a part or not.**

```lua
replicated_storage.EnterWineCellarCode.Parent = player.PlayerGui
```

In the original code, **you tried to set `StarterGui` to `EnterWineCellarCode`?** I don't know what you were going for but I'm assuming you meant to **parent `EnterWineCellarCode` to `PlayerGui`**

Lastly, you might want to use [GetDescendants()](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Instance/GetDescendants) instead of [GetChildren()](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Instance/GetChildren). To better understand how the character works I recommend you read [the wiki entry for it](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Player/Character)